# Parsing error in Android

Tags: android, integer, android-activity

I am storing an array of numbers as string(I get the string from shared preferences) and then trying to parse it.
But when I use parseInt my app crashes. The activity Second is called by Main class.

```
    public class Second extends Activity {

public int[] x = new int[50];
public int[] y = new int[50];

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.second);
    SharedPreferences data= getSharedPreferences("data",0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor= data.edit();

    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    str.append(data.getString("val", "0")).append(",").append(getIntent().getExtras().getString("thetext"));
    String end = str.toString();
    editor.putString("val", end);
    editor.commit();

    //EditText et1= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    //et1.
    String savedString = data.getString("val", "0");
    savedString.replaceAll("\\s","");
    String[] st = savedString.split(",");
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<st.length;i++){
        st[i].trim();
        Log.d("Debug" , "st["+i+"] = "+st[i]);
        x[i] = Integer.valueOf(st[i]);
       y[i]=i;}
}



public void lineGraphHandler (View view)
{
    LineGraph line = new LineGraph();
    Intent lineIntent = line.getIntent(this);
    startActivity(lineIntent);
}
```

}

Where is it going wrong?

Comment: what are the logcat errors ?

Comment: also share final number Array which u are saving in SharedPreferences

Comment: I have updated the code in question.This is the logcat http://imgur.com/m87QMry. There is something fishy here.Whatever I enter in the app, it always shows these 6 values in st(0,1,1,2,2,2)

Comment: Got it. Now I am removing spaces directly from the TextView string

Answer (score 0):

Add a line between these

```
    st[i].replaceAll("\\s","");
```

---

```
    Log.d("Debug" , "st["+i+"] = "+st[i])
```

---

```
    x[i] = Integer.parseInt(st[i]);
```

and see that if that is a convertible string or there are some letters accidently inserted that can't be converted to int?

Comment: Note: you need to import `android.util.log` and then see logcat.

Comment: Instead try `Integer.valueOf(st[i])`

Comment: Thanks :) But this is also not working. I suppose there is something else wrong here.I have updated my class in the question, please have a look at it.

Comment: Sorry, but a last time can you try for `short`?

Comment: Got it. Now I am removing spaces directly from the TextView string